# How to set the storage class uploading an object to S3 with the JS SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm using the AWS JS SDK to upload an object to S3 from the browser, using the managed uploader. I want to use the reduced redundacy storage class but I can't find a way to set it. I tried to set the x-amz-storage-class header on the request like described here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/660 but it doesn't seem to work for the managed uploader. Any idea?

The code I'm using is similar to this

```
var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket'});
var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file};
bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
  $('#results').html(err ? 'ERROR!' : 'UPLOADED.');
});
```

Found here https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/javascript/post/Tx3EQZP53BODXWF/Announcing-the-Amazon-S3-Managed-Uploader-in-the-AWS-SDK-for-JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `StorageClass` to the params.

```
var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file, StorageClass: 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'};
```

[s3 upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property)

Comment: It turns out I can't read documentation, I even looked there before :D Thanks man